# excel pulling data from another sheet based on another cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I want to pull through data from one sheet to another based upon the week number.

From the "Actuals" sheet I need to pull through the figures highlighted in the attached images depending on the week number in the "Weekly" sheet.

For example, in the "Paste to" image (Weekly tab) D2 - Week 1, i want the figures to pull through from the Actuals tab when this cell is updated for the week.

I have highlighted the cells I want to be updated in the images.

Any ideas guys?

[image: Copy From]
[image: Paste to]

Comment: Just in case it is not clear, the first picture is the "From To" picture.    and the Second picture is the "PAste To".

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly `VLOOKUP(lookup_value, table_array, col_index_num, [range_lookup])` will do this for you.

Comment: but it won't update it so that when type in figures for the next week in the "Actuals " tab it pulls through to the "weekly" tab. So for example when i type in week 5 figures in the "Actuals" tab i want the figures in "Weekly" to also be updated.

Comment: I did use the following vlookup =VLOOKUP(D6,Actuals!A7:O22,3,FALSE)

Comment: However I have to change the =VLOOKUP(D6,Actuals!A7:O22,""""""3""""(Have to change this every week),FALSE)

Comment: I know it does not look like much work but I have not completed the sheet yet and there is much more data to be inserted so it is quite a task.

Comment: Share your excel file if possible

Comment: How do you do that? @irosh

Comment: on any filesharing site, dropbox perhaps